# android- toolbar extends the screen size

Tags: android

in my app I have an activity with 3 tabs implemented with view pager and tab layout, one of them is a chat fragment.
the problem is that at the bottom of this fragment layout i have EditText and send button, which are hidden under the screen borders, when i scroll down with the nested scrolling it can be seen in the images:

[EditText and send button hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4fI7.png)

[EditText and send button apear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hXcl.png)

the activity layout .xml:

```css
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_event_details"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".eventdetails.EventDetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
            <ImageButton
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/event_creator_button"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>




    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <!--<LinearLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:orientation="vertical"-->
        <!--app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">-->

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the fragment layout(I don't think the problem is here but-for any case..):

```css
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".eventdetails.EventChatFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messageListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="SEND"/>

    </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't figure out what is the reason the app is "extend" the screen, and how to fix it. tried to search a lot but nothing helped..
thank's  a lot!

Comment: try to use `android:layout_below="@+id/messageRecyclerView"`in your linear layout.

Comment: tried this is out , but it throw error:`Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout` because I already use for the ListView: `android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"`

Comment: still throw the error because it still circular dependency between the ListView and the LinearLayout

Comment: because you have `android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"` and `android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"`

Comment: yes, this is what I tried to say.. so what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you created this activity layout through the android studio wizard choosing e.g. basic layout? Open the visual editor and you will see your LinearLayout with `height=match_parent` will have a hidden bottom part. For me I changed the android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout to RelativeLayout and used this to place the content below the toolbar.

Watch the blue border: http://postimg.org/image/dz1x2y6gb/

http://postimg.org/image/xse0vnju3/

I also came across this problem when noticing that the last items of my ListView weren't showing.

**EDIT**

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_event_details"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".eventdetails.EventDetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
            <ImageButton
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/event_creator_button"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>




    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <!--<LinearLayout-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:orientation="vertical"-->
    <!--app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">-->

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: looked there, looks OK. inside the screen border.The problem is the size of the layout not the aligment to the toolbar..anyway it is the a fragment layout, and the toolbar is under the activity layout, so that the RelativeLayout doesn't contain it, so I can't  use layout_below the toolbar.

Comment: Really? I just copied your xml and it looks like this exact problem.

Comment: I am glad I could help you ;) Would appreciate a mark as right answer ;)